# take him a lot of lectures

Tags: word-usage

> It took him numerous lectures to elucidate Saussure's linguistic
> theories.

[GISTS]

> It takes him a lot of lectures to explain the difficult theory.

Can I interpret this sentence as two opposite ways ?

To his students (*He is a teacher and he needs many lectures to give *)  or
To himself (*He is a student and he have to listen to many lectures *) ?

Comment: Do you understand the difference between 'explain' (teacher) and 'understand' (student)?

Comment: Explain is to give lecture while understand is to get or take the lecture. In this sentence above, 'take' means not to get. 'take' means kind of to 'need' or to 'cost'.

Comment: Elucidate means 'explain', thus only one meaning is possible.

Comment: Thank you m(_ _)m

  I misunderstood the meaning of 'elucidate'
as both to explain and to understand sth
in my English-Japanese dic.

But the English-English dic says,
it is to give a clarifying explanation.

Comment: It means he gave many lectures on the subject in order to make clear Saussure's linguistic theories. In other words, he didn't not just give a couple of lectures.

Comment: Thank you Lambie.; So far, this is the way I have grasped the sentence. \1: The sense subject of 'elucidate'(doer of 'elucidate') is 'he'. \2: The verb 'elucidate' seems to be used as S.V.O.(Subject-tVerb-dObject). \{Paraphrase} -> He had to attend a few [related] lectures to show the theories to either his students or to himself.

Comment: No, he was not attending lectures. He was giving them. It took me three answers to elucidate  your question. It takes [a person] [time] means the person is doing the thing.

Comment: Thank you Lambie for 'take a person'. I must learn this usage sincerely by heart.
\take a person something: A person do something for someone or for himself
\take a person ages: A person (uses | consumes | is robbed of) much time to do ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It takes him a lot of lectures to explain ABC.

It takes [some person] [some thing]  [to do something]..

That means the person (him) needs to give a lot of lectures to explain Saussure.

It took me less than a minute to write this. =
I needed less than a minute to write this.

and elucidate here means to explain.

Comment: May be the verb 'elucidate' annoyed me.
1: In this sentence, sense subject of 'elucidate' is omitted, thus HE elucidated it.
 2: In my dictionary, 'elucidate' has only direct object.{e.g.} elucidate a link between, elucidate the basis of, elucidate the roles of, ...
Therefore, I suppose 'elucidate' is similar to 'indirect verb' and the action he took was for himself.
 "He managed to make himself understood the theories by taking a few lectures."

Comment: or "He managed to solve the theories by taking a few lectures." m(_ _)m

Comment: @Kumas, okay, you're reading is different from mine. But since he is elucidating, it seems natural that he was GIVING lectures, not TAKING them. It took the professor numerous lectures to elucidate his theories.

Comment: I am gradually approaching the point.
\It took him numerous lectures to explain his or someone's theories.
He had to lecture about the theories several times
 to make his students understand what they really mean.
\By the way, it would take me 8 hours from now to acquire new energy. thank you.

Comment: @Kumas, if you are in India, you are forgiven. :)

Answer (score 0):

There's only one way to understand this.

"It takes [x] to do [y]" is a common way of stating a requirement to achieve an aim, for example:

- It takes two people to lift this furniture
- It takes three years to complete a degree

"It takes him a lot of lectures to explain the difficult theory" means that the theory cannot be explained in a single lecture - it requires "a lot".

It *could* be a suggestion that the lecturer takes longer than he should, but that would be clear in the context.

Comment: It took ages to do that.
It took him ages to do that.
It took him ages for her to do that.
...
In this topic sentence, the subject of the sentence appears only once.
So, he attended a lot of lectures to solve the theories.